# Cucumber.js Before hook not working on tagged Scenario

Tags: cucumberjs, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am writing UI tests using cypress and cucumber (with the cypress-cucumber-preprocessor).

I'm trying to write a Before hook, that will automatically delete local storage. I want to run this hook only for some of the tests (ones that have a login stage as part of the Given stage. Deleting the storage makes sure the app is not logged in when the test starts).

I'v added a tag to both the Before hook and to the Scenario, but the step in the hook is not being executed. I know this because when I run the test the login steps fail, because the storage isn't cleared and the app stays logged in from the last run.

If I delete the tag from the Before and from the Scenario, then the Before hook is executed, the local storage wiped and the login stages run without a problem.

What am i doing wrong?

Here is the hook:

```
Before({tags: "@clear_storage"},()=>{
    indexedDB.deleteDatabase('firebaseLocalStorageDb')

})
```

and the Scenarios:

```
@clear_storage
Feature: tasks view
    Scenario Outline: validate task selection buttons
        Given User is logged in
        And User is in tasks screen
        When User clicks on <task view controler> button
        Then Task <selection menu validator> is visible
        Examples:
            | task view controler | selection menu validator   |
            | tasks_status        | "All Tasks"      |
            | tasks_filter        | "My Tasks"       |
            | tasks_sort          | "Rank"           |
```

and the step definition for the Given stage:

```
onst username = 'integration-test@sedric.me'
const password = 'integration-test@sedric.me'

Given('User is logged in', ()=>{
    cy.visit('https://sedric-dev-a8294.web.app/app/')
    cy.get('#login_username_input').type(username)
    cy.get('#login_password_input').type(password)
    cy.get('#login_submit_button').click()
})
```

Comment: Have you tried by passing tag name within single quote in Hooks file?

Comment: @Sreenivasulu tried it, doesn't make a difference

Comment: Have you added any cucumber.js file in your project and added all cucumber related command line args into it?